# how to find white space between the string in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I need to find the white space between a string in ColdFusion
for example

```
str="ha    ppy"
```

Whitespace=4

i need to calculate how many white space between the str.

how to do that.

Comment: Do you want only spaces - just chr(32) - or whitespace (inc tab, newline, carriagereturn).

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase: do you want `[ ]` or `[ \n\r\t\v]` (i.e. `\s`) or something else?

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex:

```
<cfset str="ha    ppy">

<cfset spaces = reReplace(str, "\S+(\s+)\S+", "\1")>

<cfoutput>
    <pre>spaces = [#spaces#]</pre><br>
    #len(spaces)#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: This only works for lowercase letters - should probably be `[^ ]+` to exclude spaces instead (or `\S` and `\s` for whitespace). If it is just spaces though, a simpler solution would be `ListLen(str,' ',true)`

Comment: @PeterBoughton fair point about using \s \S... your listLen solution doesn't work, incorrectly returns len = 5 for this example. If the spaces are the delimiters and there are 4 delimiters then the list has 5 elements (you could always subtract 1 of course, but then your code is getting a bit messier)

Comment: Doh, yes that was meant to have a `-1` on the end. It's not really messier, and for spaces only it's probably more efficient than the regex. It's _still_ not clear if the OP wants just spaces or whitespace but the `[\S]+` you've got should just be `\S+`